# Сумма задача на жадный алгоритм!

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Всем привет есть задача! Я её решил перебором, но эту задачу нужно решить жадным алгоритмом. Пожалуйста помогите мне решить эту задачу! И также вы можете подкинуть мне, где я могу прочитать про жадный алгоритм и на каких сайтах могу решить?

Вот задача:

Задано натуральное число `x`. Найдите число способов представить его в виде суммы четырех натуральных чисел: `x = a + b + c + d`, где `a <= b <= c <= d`.

Входной файл `INPUT.TXT` содержит целое число `x` (`1 <= x <= 1500`).
В выходной файл `OUTPUT.TXT` выведите ответ на задачу.

Примеры

Входные данные: 3
Ответ: 0

Входные данные: 5
Ответ: 1

Comment: Что-то не похоже, чтобы эта задача решалась жадно. Или перебор, или динамика же?

Comment: Это считается аналитически (без программирования). Более жадный алгоритм придумать трудно.

Comment: попробуй упростить перебор до нескольких строк

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое жадное - в смысле вычислительных ресурсов и времени - вычисление выглядит так:

```
long long count(long long n)
{
    return (((n+3)*n-9*(n%2))*n+72)/144;
}
```

См. Кнут, *"Искусство программирования"*, т.4А, задача 7.2.1.4-31.

Сравнивал со своим решением

```
long long count(long n, long k = 4, long min = 1)
{
    if (n < min*k) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return 1;
    long long sum = 0;
    for(long long i = min; i <= n/k; ++i)
        sum += count(n-i,k-1,i);
    return sum;
}
```

Дает то же значение.

Answer (score 1):

Если чисто `N` необходимо разложить на `K` слагаемых, то "разумный" алгоритм решения такой задачи будет основан на том факте, что для того, чтобы последовательность слагаемых была неубывающей, *необходимо*, чтобы первое слагаемое не превосходило `[N / K]` (более того, это еще и *достаточное* условие существования последовательности с таким первым слагаемым).

Отсюда получаем очевидный алгоритм: перебираем все возможные первые слагаемые `S` в диапазоне от `1` до `[N / K]`, после чего применяем ту же самую логику для `N - S` и `K - 1`.

Будет ли такой алгоритм "жадным" в вашем определении - трудно сказать. Традиционная идея "жадного" алгоритма состоит в градиентной ("жадной") оптимизации некоей целевой функции. Я в данном случае не вижу никакой оптимизируемой целевой функции.

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под N и K ?

Comment: @futuretourist: Я подправил первое предложение, чтобы ввести `N` и `K`. `K` в вашем случае - 4, а `N` - это ваш `x`.

Comment: Спасибо @AnT попробую!

Comment: Ваш код можно оптимизировать - ведь поскольку следующее значение в разложении не может быть меньше предыдущего, нужно начинать цикл с `i = 1` только для первого вызова, но не для последующих. Кстати, он, похоже, вообще будет неверно работать из-за этого... Да, работает неверно.

Comment: Решение @Harry прошло! А вашем коде есть ошибки.Согласен с Harry

Answer (score 0):

Задача больше математическая. Представим х как сумму единичек: х = 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1. Чтобы представить х как сумму 4 слагаемых, нужно разбить эту сумму единиц на 4 (как бы скобки расставить). Ну вот так, возможно, нагляднее даже будет: представим х как сумму счётных палочек: х = |.|.|.|....| Точки назовём "дырками", тогда для того, чтобы поделить это на 4 части, нужно "занять" 3 дырки. Это можно сделать С(3,х) (число сочетаний из Х по 4) способами. Но здесь только будут все варианты, поэтому результат надо еще поделить на 4!, чтобы отсортировать по возрастанию.

UPD: Делить не на 4!, а на меньшее число, нужно учитывать, что числа могут оказаться равны и тогда делить надо на меньшее число. Сходу так не придумал, а думать дольше сейчас нет времени, увы(

Comment: спасибо ,попробую! Но мне также интересен вариант с жадным алгоритмом,так как я сейчас его изучаю.

Comment: Ну и что будет, например, для 17? 17!/(3!*14!*4!) - дробное...

Comment: вы что предлагаете @Harry ?

Comment: @Harry исправил ответ, не учел, что если слагаемые одинаковые (а такое точно будет), то нужно этот момент прибавить обратно